# gazebo urdf tutorial robots not visible

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am virtualizing in virtual box a copy of ubuntu 11.10 for a robotics class. I have ros electric installed. I have 3d acceleration enabled.
My problem is whenever I load a model from the urdf tutorials into gazebo, such as the visual robot, it is not rendered. Either nothing is rendered or only the root link is rendered. 
Simple objects such as the tables or primitives are rendered.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32858/gazebo-urdf-tutorial-robots-not-visible/) by [avatarofwill13](https://answers.ros.org/users/2261/avatarofwill13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-04-28**:
Please be more specific when asking a question, i.e. reference models you are having trouble with.  In general, if you would like to dynamically simulate things in gazebo, you need to add physical properties (e.g. inertial elements), see http://ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Adding%20Physical%20and%

**Comment by [avatarofwill13](https://answers.ros.org/users/2261/avatarofwill13/) on 2012-04-28**:
One of the models was called visual, which was my reference. its the end result of the building a visual robot model in urdf from scratch. its in the urdf_tutorial package with the model name 05-visual.urdf.  Do all links need physical properties to be visible or only the main link?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-04-28**:
all links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The models in the URDF tutorials are not meant for Gazebo, only RViz.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to add  properties to all links in order to visualize them in gazebo

---

Originally posted by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) with karma: 53 on 2012-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This really is ridiculous:

Even for virtual links like plate_footprint or if you wanna have more dof at one joint you need at least to add inertial and a mass value and an inertia of none zero:

```
<link name="plate_footprint" >
<inertial>
   <origin rpy="${0} 0 0" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
   <mass value="0.001" />
   <inertia ixx="0.001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.001" iyz="0" izz="0.001" />
</inertial>
</link>
```

---

Originally posted by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) with karma: 311 on 2018-08-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1